# Read only Exif "part" of image in Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, exif

I'm creating a [Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html) application that will show a slideshow of images. The images will be ordered by the [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) date. I believe that the file dates are changed when you copy the files etc., but that is just my observation, I want to sort by Exif date anyway.

The application will need to show a slideshow of thousands of photos, so I can't load every image at the start because it would obviously take too long. My idea was to create a class like this:

```
@interface ImageRep : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSURL *imageURL;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *dateTaken;

@end
```

It represents an image on the disk. When the user sets the folder, the application scans the images and creates an instance of `ImageRep` for each image. It then sorts them according to `dateTaken`. Then it reads the current image from the `imageURL`.

The problem is, how do I read the Exif data from an image without reading the whole image?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a reusable component in Cocoa you could use for this purpose but you could always do the EXIF parsing on your own. Check [here](http://code.flickr.net/2012/06/01/parsing-exif-client-side-using-javascript-2/) for an example of how to do it in JavaScript. It's actually not that hard once you get the hang of it.